# How is the database in this application getting populated?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-resources

I am using this application: https://code.google.com/p/androidtutorial/ as part of learning to develop Android apps. I am totally new to this. In Eclipse I look through the source code, but I don't see the actual employee list (i.e. the file with the names/numbers etc). I'm guessing either I am looking in the wrong place or it links to a list held online or something? I'm sure it's obvious to anyone who understands these things, but I want to understand where the information is and where in the code this database/list is referenced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The list they are referring to is a local database on a computer, meaning you probably don't have it. It is just an example to show how to interact with a database.

Comment: But when I create an APK from the code and run the application on my phone the search function returns results from the (Example) database. I realise the databse is only something made up for the learning process, but if the results show on the my phone clearly it's either included in the application or is connecting to a text file online that has it, for example. Am I right?

Comment: An android application cannot read a local database that is not present on the device itself (i.e. it cannot read a db file from your development PC, without some other interface that connects the two) The db file must be contained within the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that example project but I think the [sql.xml](https://code.google.com/p/androidtutorial/source/browse/trunk/%20androidtutorial/EmployeeDirectory6/res/raw/sql.xml) file that is inside of `EmployeeDirectory6/res/raw/` is where the data is coming from.

There is some code inside of `DatabaseHelper.java` that executes the SQL commands that are contained within this file to populate the database.